# Docker container loosing network when my host machine switches network (Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, networking, docker

I use docker on my laptop when I'm developing, a macbook air running docker-machine.

Since I develop on a laptop I want to be able to go out and about and drink my oat-milk cappuccino at my local coffee shop while still doing work with my containers.

My problem is that every time I switch network, from Work to home, from home to café, etc. , my container looses its internet connection even though the host machine has a working internet connection.

My usual workaround is to restart the docker-machine with:

```
$ docker-machine restart
$ eval $(docker-machine env)
```

And then fire up my container again.

But I find doing this annoying, I expected the container to "just work" when the host machine has an internet connection. Is it something I'm missing? Do you also have this annoyance when switching networks? What are your solutions to this issue?

Please tell me if there is anything that is unclear.

Thank you!